# Tab select event is triggered when I am navigating away

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the Tab directive and the select expression to trigger a method when the tab is loaded. But the event is also triggered when I am navigating away from the site. How can I avoid this?

I have created a small example on github.
https://github.com/mkeuschn/management-reporting

### Behaviour:

- When I use the Report link the tab event of the first tab is fired. OK
- If I am navigating away from the report part (press the home button), then the event of the second tab is fired. NOK

regards,
Marko

### Update

I have created a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/7NQwVGa7tpBDNRbIckZk?p=preview

#### Github Issue

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2155

Comment: I really need help with this one too. It basically makes tabs worthless if it blocks fundamental browser functions from working at all

Comment: @Marko, any luck so far?

Comment: At the moment I have removed the tab directive with "plain" twitter bootstrap code.

Comment: Did this patch work for you? https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/9939867aba0b7b763588b18829b557c052ea69ba

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Angular-UI v0.11.2. After checking out related issue on github, i saw that it is fixed and merged into master branch.

I applied this [patch](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/9939867aba0b7b763588b18829b557c052ea69ba) and it worked as expected.